# Tokenizing Text in JTextComponent at every non-alpha-numeric character

Tags: java, swing, awt, keyevent

I am trying to implement auto-complete feature to the Text Editor I have developed in Java. To implement auto-complete, I need all (distinct) words that have already been typed into editor.

A direct implementation would be to convert the JTextComponent into string and then tokenizing. Instead Is there a way to remember where the last non alpha-numeric character has been typed, start recording the string until another non alpha-numeric character is typed and then add this recorded string to set of words in my auto-complete dictionary?

```
/*Contains only parts of code that is relavant to the question*/
public class Editor {
    private JFrame editorFrame;
    /*this is where text typed is shown*/
    private JTextComponent textComp;

    /*autoComplete contains all words in the entered text*/
    /*private TreeSet<String> autoComplete*/
    /*private JMenu autoCompleteMenu*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Editor editor = new Editor();
            editor.Launch();
    }

    private void Launch() {
            editorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            editorFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            editorFrame.setVisible(true);
            editorFrame.pack();
    }

    public Editor() {
            editorFrame = new JFrame("Critter");
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("", 46, 115);
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            textComp = (JTextComponent)ta;
    }
    /*
    Iam trying to implement the following
    */
    /*
        specialChars = {all special characters,space,tab}
        if typed character is in specialChars:
            while KeyEvent is alpha-numeric :
                record KeyEvent to a string
                search for this recorded string in autoComplete and create autoCompleteMenu of possible completions
                if autoCompleteMenu != null:
                    display autoCompleteMenu

        add string to autoComplete
    */
    /*I want to know how to detect the keyevent belonging to specialChars and recording the string */
}
```

Comment: Please post the sample code

Comment: I have added relevant portions of the original source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except typing there is PASTE action where more than one char is added. But anyway you can use DocumentListener processing insertUpdate/removeUpdate/changedUpdate and adapting your code according to newly added content. 
The DocumentEvent has offset/lenght so you can track added text.

To avoid attempt to mutate in notification problem wrap your call in SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Comment: I actually know a way using CaretListener, which is similar to using offset/length in DocumentEvent. The disadvantage I thought about this method is, given a document of large size (say >100KB), we would be dealing with large offsets, which would decrease performance. Is there a better way out of this?